# How would you prove the series $\{\frac{1}{n^2+1}\}$ from 0 to infinity converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I understand you would usually compare it with $\{\frac{1}{n^2}\}$ if $n=1$, which converges, but this series starts at $n = 0$ which is undefined for $\{\frac{1}{n^2}\}$ which is the start point of this series.

Comment: It doesn't matter what happens at $n=0$. We only care about large $n$, and for large $n$ we have $0<\frac{1}{n^2 + 1} < \frac{1}{n^2}$ so the series converges by comparison.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n^2+1}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2+1}$$
Adding one (or any finite number) cannot change whether the sum converges, so the comparison you mention with $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$ is sufficient to establish convergence.